# How to transform a row to a column and add it to the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have 5 different tables as shown in the pictures.

I can combine them using that query but i want to add book read log with using book names as column name into that table.
I show my tables in picture with different colors.

```
select dbo.Users.name+' '+dbo.Users.surname AS name_surname,
       dbo.Student_Facebook_Data.likes,
       dbo.Student_Facebook_Data.posts,
       dbo.Student_Facebook_Data.comments,
       dbo.Attendance.absence,dbo.Attendance.physical_presence,
       dbo.Attendance.virtual_presence 
from dbo.Users inner join dbo.Student_Facebook_Data on dbo.Users.id=dbo.Student_Facebook_Data.student_id 
inner join dbo.Attendance on dbo.Users.id=dbo.Attendance.student_id
```

I tried that queries but these are doesn't solve my problem:

```
select dbo.Users.name+' '+dbo.Users.surname AS name_surname ,dbo.Student_Log.content_id 
from dbo.Student_Log inner join 
     dbo.Users on dbo.Student_Log.student_id=dbo.Users.id

select distinct(material_name) 
from dbo.Material_Detail inner join 
     dbo.Student_Log on dbo.Student_Log.content_id=convert(varchar,dbo.Material_Detail.id)

select distinct(material_name) 
from dbo.Material_Detail inner join 
     dbo.Student_Log on dbo.Student_Log.content_id=convert(varchar,dbo.Material_Detail.id)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your database is SQL Server 2005 or higher, you can definitely do it using the PIVOT operator. For clarity, I'm only showing how to display the count for books and using simplified table names:

```
select * from (
select u.name as 'user_name',
       b.name as 'book_name',
       l.id as 'reading'
from dbo.Users u
left join dbo.RealLog l on u.id = l.user_id
left join dbo.Books b on l.bid = b.id
) x
pivot (count(reading) for book_name in ([one],[two],[three],[four],[five])) as count
```

PIVOT Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx